# Parse PFQueryTableViewController objectsDidLoad not executing before numberOfRowsInSection

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform, pfquery

So, I'm having a strange problem. I'm using Parse's iOS APIs, and using a PFQueryTableViewController to display items to the user. These items are organized into two sections. When the application first starts, it runs the `objectsDidLoad` method BEFORE it runs the `numberOfRowsInSection` method. This is perfect because the `objectsDidLoad` method is able to define the number of objects present in each section of the table view. I am also enabling the tableView's "pull-down to refresh" capabilities, which is working perfectly. So, if I change a certain data value on my parse data browser, this should cause one of the items being displayed to the user to change sections. If I restart the app after changing that data value, the object appears in the other section like it should. The problem, however, is if I change the data value on parse to cause the object to change sections, and then pull down the tableView to refresh the data, the app crashes and I think I know why. Although the `objectsDidLoad` method executes BEFORE the `numberOfRowsInSection` method the first time the app runs, it actually executes AFTER the `numberOfRowsInSection` when I pull down the tableView and refresh the data. This causes the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method to attempt to access an array index that doesn't exist in the arrays storing the objects in each section.

My question: How do I refresh the objects and update the arrays storing the objects for each section BEFORE the `numberOfRowsInSection` method gets called?

Here's my `objectsDidLoad` method:

```
    - (void)objectsDidLoad:(NSError *)error {
       //dataArray, firstSectionArray, and secondSectionArray are global NSMutableArrays
       [super objectsDidLoad:error];

       firstSectionArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
       secondSectionArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
       NSMutableDictionary *firstSectionDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
       NSMutableDictionary *secondSectionDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
       dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

       for (int i = 0; i < [self.objects count]; i++) {
           if ([[[self.objects objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey@"Level"]intValue] == 1) {
               [firstSectionArray addObject:[self.objects objectAtIndex:i]];
           }
           else {
               [secondSectionArray addObject:[self.objects objectAtIndex:i]];
           }
       }

       firstSectionDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:firstSectionArray forKey:@"data"];
       secondSectionDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:secondSectionArray forKey:@"data"];
       [dataArray addObject:firstSectionDictionary];
       [dataArray addObject:secondSectionDictionary];
    }
```

Here's my `numberOfRowsInSection` method:

```
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        NSDictionary *dictionary = [dataArray objectAtIndex:section];
        NSMutableArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"data"];
        return [array count];
    }
```

Here's my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        PFTableViewCell *cell = (PFTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[PFTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

        NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        //This next line is where it's crashing
        PFObject *newObject = [[dictionary objectForKey:@"data"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        //More irrelevant code below..........
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I have fixed the issue by multithreading my app. I've used a global `BOOL` called `isDoneLoading` to check whether or not the `objectsDidLoad` method has completed executing. Here's my `objectsDidLoad` method:

```
- (void)objectsDidLoad:(NSError *)error {
     [super objectsDidLoad:error];

     dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

     NSMutableArray *firstSectionArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

     NSMutableArray *secondSectionArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

     for (int i = 0; i < [self.objects count]; i++) {
         //First Section
         if ([[[self.objects objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"Level"]intValue] == 1) {
             [firstSectionArray addObject:[self.objects objectAtIndex:i]];
         }
         //Second Section
         else  {
             [secondSectionArray addObject:[self.objects objectAtIndex:i]];
             /*} else {
              //Other Sections
              [secondSectionArray addObject:[self.objects objectAtIndex:i]];
              }*/
         }
     }

     NSMutableDictionary *firstSectionDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:firstSectionArray forKey:@"data"];
     [dataArray addObject:firstSectionDictionary];

      NSMutableDictionary *secondSectionDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:secondSectionArray forKey:@"data"];
     [dataArray addObject:secondSectionDictionary];

     isDoneLoading = true;
 }
```

Here's my `numberOfRowsInSection` method:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    dispatch_group_t d_group = dispatch_group_create();
    dispatch_queue_t bg_queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

    __block NSDictionary *dictionary;
    __block NSMutableArray *array;

    dispatch_group_async(d_group, bg_queue, ^{
       // [self queryForTable];
        [self objectsDidLoad:NULL];
        while (!isDoneLoading) {}

        dictionary = [dataArray objectAtIndex:section];
        array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"data"];
    });

    dispatch_group_wait(d_group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    isDoneLoading = false;
    return [array count];
}
```

Using this method of multithreading, I am capable of always preventing the `numberOfRowsInSection` method from executing before the `objectsDidLoad` method.

Comment: Dope. A much needed thingy. I'm having exact same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add this At the end of your `objectsDidLoad` Method

```
if(self.tableView.numberOfSections != self.sections.allKeys.count)
    {
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
```